# Does current Church doctrine/law allow the veneration of a saint's social media accounts?

Tags: catholicism, saint, veneration

Imagine a hypothetical scenario of a holy Catholic in our century. This person owns a Facebook account, a blog, and an Instagram account. After death and much deliberation by the Vatican, this person is canonized as a saint. The social media accounts of said saint persist to this date and Vatican knows about them.

Would these accounts be treated like holy relics? If yes, do they have to be saved in physical storage at the time of the presentation of the relics? Thanks!

Comment: Accounts are not physical (whether on Facebook, or at a bank), and thus are not subject to "physical storage." If you mean the posts on their accounts, then surely the same rules would apply to Facebook posts as to books, letters, tv and radio broadcasts, since antiquity.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify specifically what you're asking about. And to help anyone who might answer, you might indicate why you feel this is a unique situation that wouldn't be addressed by existing laws/situations.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  What Saint are you aware of that has social media accounts?  Who have you recently nominated for beatification whose virtual presence is important enough for the Vatican to address this question? (Assuming they even would ...)

Comment: This question is interesting to think about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**

What is the Church's definition of a holy relic?

"A [relic](http://www.motherteresa.org/09_relics/relics.htm) is something connected with a saint or blessed, including a part of their body (e.g. hair or a piece of bone), their clothing, or an object that the person used or touched."

[Relics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic) are classified into three categories:

**First Class Relics:** items directly associated with the events of Christ's life (manger, cross, etc.) or the physical remains of a saint (a bone, a hair, skull, a limb, etc.). Traditionally, a martyr's relics are often more prized than the relics of other saints. Parts of the saint that were significant to that saint's life are more prized relics. For instance, King St. Stephen of Hungary's right forearm is especially important because of his status as a ruler. A famous theologian's head may be his most important relic. (The head of St. Thomas Aquinas was removed by the monks at the Cistercian abbey at Fossanova where he died.) If a saint did a lot of traveling, then the bones of his feet may be prized. Catholic teaching prohibits relics to be divided up into small, unrecognizable parts if they are to be used in liturgy (i.e., as in an altar; see the rubrics listed in Rite of Dedication of a Church and an Altar).

**Second Class Relics:** items that the saint owned or frequently used, for example, a crucifix, rosary, book, etc. Again, an item more important in the saint's life is thus a more important relic. Sometimes a second-class relic is a part of an item that the saint wore (a shirt, a glove, etc.) and is known as ex indumentis ("from the clothing").

**Third Class Relics:** any object that is touched to a first- or second-class relic.[38] Most third-class relics are small pieces of cloth, though in the first millennium oil was popular; the Monza ampullae contained oil collected from lamps burning before the major sites of Christ's life, and some reliquaries had holes for oil to be poured in and out again. Many people call the cloth touched to the bones of saints "ex brandea". But ex brandea strictly refers to pieces of clothing that were touched to the body or tombs of the apostles. It is a term that is used only for such; it is not a synonym for a third-class relic.

Since online accounts do not possess the physical properties of what the Catholic Church defines as a relic, they would not be even remotely considered as such.